# Преобразование даты из свободного формата в нужный вид

Tags: php, инспекция-кода, время

При парсинге получаем переменную даты в формате "10 июля 2017", и нужно её записать в базу msql, соотвественно в формате "2017-07-10".

Я написал, но можно ли мой говнокод оптимизировать?

```
    <?

$ddate = "10 июля 2017";

// нужно превратить "10 июля 2017" в msql - формат даты 2017-07-10

// Первое - найдем до пробелов от начала и до конца строки
$probel1 = strpos($ddate, " ");

// вырежем день
$day = substr ($ddate, 0, $probel1 );

// остаток строки с месяцем и годом
$dayandmonth = substr ($ddate, $probel1+1);

// место пробела в остатке месяца и года
$probel2 = strpos($dayandmonth, " ");

// месяц (до пробела)
$month = substr ($dayandmonth, 0, $probel2);

// год (от пробела)
$year = substr ($dayandmonth, $probel2+1);

// заменим месяц числом
switch ($month) {
    case "января": $newmonth = "01"; break;
    case "февраля": $newmonth = "02"; break;
    case "марта": $newmonth = "03"; break;
    case "апреля": $newmonth = "04"; break;
    case "мая": $newmonth = "05"; break;
    case "июня": $newmonth = "06"; break;
    case "июля": $newmonth = "07"; break;
    case "августа": $newmonth = "08"; break;
    case "сентября": $newmonth = "09"; break;
    case "октября": $newmonth = "10"; break;
    case "ноября": $newmonth = "11"; break;
    case "декабря": $newmonth = "12"; break;
}

echo $year."-".$newmonth."-".$day;


?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$input = "10 июля 2017";
$months = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];

//------------------------------------------------------
// разбиваем по пробелам
$arr = explode(' ', $input);
// меняем ключи и значения местами, чтобы можно было искать по названием месяцев
// а можно сразу задать ассоциативный массив, 
// где ключи - названия месяцев значения - номер, чтоб не мудрить
$months = array_flip($months);
// индекс месяца - это ячейка  в массиве $months со значением $arr[1]
$newmonth = $months[$arr[1]] + 1;
// если индекс меньше 10 - добавляем ноль
$newmonth = $newmonth > 9 ? $newmonth : '0'.$newmonth;
// результат
$output = $arr[2].'-'.$newmonth.'-'.$arr[0];
//------------------------------------------------------

echo $output;
```

---

без мудрежа

```
$input = "10 мая 2017";
$months = ['января' => '01', 'февраля' => '02', 'марта' => '03', 'апреля' => '04', 'мая' => '05', 'июня' => '06', 'июля' => '07', 'августа' => '08', 'сентября' => '09', 'октября' => '10', 'ноября' => '11', 'декабря' => '12'];
//------------------------------------------------------
$arr = explode(' ', $input);    
$output = $arr[2].'-'.$months[$arr[1]].'-'.$arr[0];
//------------------------------------------------------

echo $output;
```

Comment: Лучшее решение однозначно.

Answer (score 2):

Чуть-чуть расширена задача и не совсем нормальный код ;)

```
function replDate($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('%^(\d{1,2})\s(?:(янв)|(фев)|(мар)|(апр)|(ма)|(июн)|(июл)|(авг)|(сен)|(окт)|(ноя)|(дек))\S*\s(\d{4})$%ui',
        function($matches) {
            $year = array_pop($matches);
            array_shift($matches);
            $day = array_shift($matches);
            $matches = array_flip($matches);
            unset($matches['']);
            $month = array_pop($matches) + 1;
            return sprintf('%s-%02s-%02s', $year, $month, $day);
        },
        $str);
}
foreach(['10 июля 2017', '1 янв 2017', '31 май 2017', '8 Июня 2999'] as $d) {
    var_dump(replDate($d));    
}
```

Вывод

```
string(10) "2017-07-10"
string(10) "2017-01-01"
string(10) "2017-05-31"
string(10) "2999-06-08"
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e17a72cfc4a42b87afcc4601971ae900e539398

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YtUm3UCV2gg/hqdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0):

используйте функцию preg_replace_callback

```
       $text = "10 июля 2017";

  // функция обратного вызова
  function new_date($matches) 
  {
    // как обычно: $matches[0] -  полное вхождение шаблона
    // $matches[1] - вхождение первой подмаски,
    // заключенной в круглые скобки, и так далее...
    $month = trim($matches[2]);

    $month_array = array(
        "января" => "01",
        "февраля"=> "02",
        "марта"=> "03",
        "апреля"=> "04",
        "мая" => "05",
        "июня" => "06",
        "июля" => "07",
        "августа" => "08",
        "сентября" => "09",
        "октября" => "10",
        "ноября" => "11",
        "декабря" => "12", 
        );
        //если введен месяц не правильно, вывожу 01, а вы у себя сами решите как быть
    $newmonth = isset($month_array[$month]) ?  $month_array[$month] : '01';  

    return $matches[3].'-'.$newmonth.'-'.$matches[1];
  }

  echo preg_replace_callback(
              "|^(\d{2})(.*)(\d{4})$|",
              "new_date",
              $text);
```